# How to make UploadedFile invalid for UnitTest?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, laravel-5

I am making a test for uploading a file in Laravel 5.1 project.

One of the checking in validation method looks like this

```
//assuming $file is instance of UploadedFile class
if ( ! $file->isValid()) {
    /*add errors and return*/
}
```

And I need to test this check.
**The question is:** How do I create an ***invalid*** uploaded file ?
(`UploadedFile` extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File` class which extends `SplFileInfo` php class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often find it's helpful to look at the library source:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php

You can see that the `isValid` method checks if `$this->error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK`, which is the default.

The only way to set `error`, since it's a private variable, is through the constructor:

```
public function __construct($path, $originalName, $mimeType = null, $size = null, $error = null, $test = false)
```

So when creating your $file object, just make sure to set $error to something. Here's all of the available error constants:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

So for example you could do this:

```
$file = new UploadedFile($path, $origName, $mimeType, UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE, true);
```

The last parameter is needed when testing to disable checking that file was uploaded via HTTP (in case your test actually creates file)

Comment: Yeah, in the end I ended up with the same code. Thanks for the help and specialy for link to the list of errors!

Comment: if I am not mistaken, it is also not bad idea to pass `$test` variable as `true` to constructor, because if I need `isValid()` to be true in some test the `is_uploaded_file(...)` part of `isValid()` may give you `false`, if file was not uploaded through HTTP. Please correct me if I am wrong or edit you answer otherwise.